# when clause with the continuous tense

Tags: clauses

> I always eat a lot of meat when I am visiting that place.

I think it means "while I am visiting that place I am always eating a lot of meat".

However, I think it can mean

> I always eat a lot of meat when I am going to visit that place.

It's a different meaning. The bottom line is this:

> **when I am doing** can mean:
>
> a) while I am doing
>
> b) when I am going to do

Do you agree?

Comment: It could in theory mean that, but it would be very odd to express it that way, without using _going to, planning to_ or similar.

Comment: But this problematic meaning is easily expressed without the tools you mention in this sentence isn't it? I always pack my bags a day early when I'm visiting the village.

Comment: _I always pack my bags a day early when I'm visiting the village_ would most likely be understood to refer to a forthcoming visit because it's normal to pack bags before going somewhere. However, we don't normally talk about changing our eating habits in preparation for a visit

Comment: But it's a matter of common sense or tradition.

Comment: Exactly. Common sense tells us that you pack before a journey, and talk about what you ate while you were away.